# How to order by latest nested model created_at in a query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a question, I don't know if this is possible but suppose these models

```ruby
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :gifs
end

class Gif < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
end
```

blank database using `rails console` you do this

```ruby
gif_1 = Gif.create
gif_2 = Gif.create
gif_3 = Gif.create
event_1 = Event.new
event_1.gifs = [gif_1, gif_3]
event_1.save
event_2 = Event.new
event_2.gifs = [gif_2]
event_2.save
```

How would you order events by their last gifs created's `created_at` attribute.

Here is an example of what I've tried but that doesn't produce the correct result

```ruby
ordered_events = Event.includes(:gifs).joins(:gifs).order("gifs.created_at DESC")
ordered_events.first.id
=> 2 # I want this to return 1
```

Now I understand why my attempt probably didn't work. I think it's because it probably only looked at the first `Gif` to do the ordering.

On top of this I had another thought, and here I have no idea where to begin trying to do this in a query, but what if the `Event` has 0 `Gif`, from what I wrote it seems no gifs simply relegates those events to after the ones who do have gifs but this would not work for me.

here's another context in `rails console` which is more realistic since normally you'd need an event first to store the `Gif`

```ruby
event_1 = Event.create
event_2 = Event.create
gif_1 = Gif.create(event_id: event_1.id)
gif_2 = Gif.create(event_id: event_2.id)
event_1 = Event.create
gif_3 = Gif.create(event_id: event_1.id)
```

Now here what I would like to get back from my query would be something of the sorts of `[event_1, event_3, event_2]` because since `event_3` has no gifs I want to use his `created_at` to order.

I know how I could do this by hand via some helper function or other but I would really love to be able to this kind of thing in one query directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example:

```
Event.joins(:gifs)
     .group('events.id')
     .order('MAX(gifs.created_at) DESC')
```

This query takes `events`, joins them with `gifs`, groups by `event.id` (to eliminate event duplicates in case one event has several gifs) and sorts result by latest (maximal) `created_at` time of event's gifs, in descending order.

Since it uses `joins` method, which unwraps to `INNER JOIN` in SQL query, events without gifs won't be returned by this query. To fix it use `left_outer_joins`:

```
Event.left_outer_joins(:gifs)
     .group('events.id')
     .order('MAX(gifs.created_at) DESC')
```

Comment: Going to try this out later, but this sounds right I completely forgot about `MAX()` thanks. How would I go about using `event.created_at` when there wouldn't be any gifs for that event ? (Second example in my question)

Comment: Well, you can use ```event.created_at``` in case event has no gifs. The order expression depends on database. For PostgreSQL it will be ```COALESCE(MAX(gifs.created_at), MAX(events.created_at)) DESC```

Comment: got errors with your queries, for the second one I got `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "gifs"`

Comment: I updated the query, added ```references``` call. Try now please

Comment: got another error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "gifs.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. By the way first query doesn't produce an error, but it only returns 2 events in my second scenario (just tested it)

Comment: "first query only returns 2 events in my second scenario (just tested it)" - that's right, it returns events with gifs; I noticed that in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181507/discussion-between-james-woodrow-and-ilya-konyukhov).

Comment: Didn't understand that in your answer the first time I read it but makes sense now, still can't seem to get the second one to work though